# Is there a way to find the number of task instance in Locust?

Tags: python, locust

I want my locust program to run a set of tasks every 10th time. I.e in the below code, out of 10 task instances I want task1 to run in all and task2, task3 to run only once. How to do that?

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost:8085/api/"
    wait_time = constant(1)

    @task
    class SequenceOfTasks(SequentialTaskSet):
        id = None
        application_json = 'application/json'

        @task(10)
        def task1(self):
            request = read_json('order.json')
            self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            request['id'] = self.id
            response = self.client.post('createRequest', json.dumps(request),
                                        headers={'Content-Type': self.application_json})
            assert response.status_code == 200

        @task(1)
        def task2(self):
            request={self.id}
            response = self.client.post('cancelRequest', json.dumps(request),
                                        headers={'Content-Type': self.application_json})
            assert response.status_code == 200

        @task(1)
        def task3(self):
            request = read_json('updateRequest.json')
            request['id'] = self.id
            response = self.client.post('updaterequest', json.dumps(request),
                                        headers={'Content-Type': self.application_json})
            assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: I dont really understand the question. What do you mean by "the number of task instance"?

Answer (score 0):

Bit hacky, but this may help your cause:

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    host = "http://localhost:8085/api/"
    wait_time = constant(1)

    @task
    class SequenceOfTasks(SequentialTaskSet):
        id = None
        application_json = 'application/json'
        def count = 0

        @task
        def controller_task(self):
          self.count++
          if self.count % 10 == 0:
             self.task1()
             self.task2()
             self.task3()
          else:
             self.task1()

        def task1(self):
            request = read_json('order.json')
            self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())
            request['id'] = self.id
            response = self.client.post('createRequest', json.dumps(request),
                                        headers={'Content-Type': self.application_json})
            assert response.status_code == 200

        def task2(self):
            request={self.id}
            response = self.client.post('cancelRequest', json.dumps(request),
                                        headers={'Content-Type': self.application_json})
            assert response.status_code == 200

        def task3(self):
            request = read_json('updateRequest.json')
            request['id'] = self.id
            response = self.client.post('updaterequest', json.dumps(request),
                                        headers={'Content-Type': self.application_json})
            assert response.status_code == 200
```

Comment: @kharash-markownikoff -- did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Aritra Nayak is good. I only want to add: if you want the controller_task to run exactly every 1 second, you should try to replace `wait_time = constant(1)` with `wait_time = constant_pacing(1)`. Refer to: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.wait_time

Comment: Hi Hong Phi Nguyen, welcome to SO. By definition, this is not really an answer for this site, it is more of a comment. When you have enough reputation, you will be able to comment on other posts. Thanks